# How to store local states in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

How to store local states in react-query?

For example, I have a modal window, the visibility of which I want to store in a separate hook, but so that I can get this state anywhere in my application, I try like this:

```
export const useSidebar = () => {
  const [isOpen, cycleOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const visible = () => {
    useQuery('sideBarVisible', () => cycleOpen(true));
  };

  return {
    isOpen,
    visible,
  };
};
```

But I get the error, in other words, how to store the visibility state globally like in redux?

Comment: I am not sure of what you want to do, but to store data globally like redux, you can use the React context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to avoid context.

Comment: @trickysneak any particular reason why you want to avoid context, which is specifically created for having "global"-like values ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use React context, which combined with a `useState` can create a value that can be accessed by all children of the context, where all components using it will re-render upon an update to its value.

```js
const SidebarContext = React.createContext(false);

const SidebarProvider = ({ children, initialValue = false }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(initialValue);

  return (
    <SidebarContext.Provider value={[isOpen, setIsOpen]}>
      {children}
    </SidebarContext.Provider>
  );
};

// this is not required, it is just the same as using React.useContext, 
// it just changes the two imports for useContext + SidebarContext,
// with a single useSidebar import.
// i left it here because you might want to do more stuff in here
const useSidebar = () => {
  const contextValue = React.useContext(SidebarContext);
  return contextValue;
};

// this is to showcase the shared value
const UsingSidebar1 = () => {
  const [isOpen] = useSidebar();

  return (
    <div className="bordered">
      <h5>UsingSidebar1 component</h5>
      Sidebar is: {isOpen.toString()}
    </div>
  );
};

// this is to showcase the shared value and how the change 
// updates all relevant components
const UsingSidebar2 = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useSidebar();

  return (
    <div className="bordered">
      <h5>UsingSidebar2 component</h5>
      Sidebar is: {isOpen.toString()}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setOpen(!isOpen)}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <SidebarProvider initialValue={false}>
    <UsingSidebar1 />
    <UsingSidebar2 />
  </SidebarProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```css
.bordered {
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

h5{ margin:0 0 0.5em 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```